# Sharing large assets between app and extension while supporting iOS7

Tags: ios, nsbundle, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget, ios-app-group

At its basic level my app could be described as a viewer for a large (61M) readonly sqlite database. I am developing a today extension which will require access to this database, but I am struggling to find a way to share this data.

These are the options as I know them with the problems which stops me from using them:

- Copy the data from the bundle to an app group on launch - this doubles the storage requirements for my app.
- Do not store the database in the app bundle and download it - this creates a terrible first launch experience
- Create a framework and store in it in the framework - this prevents me from supporting iOS7

Is there a solution or way round these issues?

Comment: I would do the first one.  128MB isn't that big

Comment: Unfortunately I hear my users struggling with storage issues constantly (its why many are not on iOS8) so I am keen to avoid doubling storage requirements.

Comment: Can you compress the database in the bundle and unzip it to the app group directory on first launch?

Comment: Yep - you've made me think about trying harder to reduce the size of the database and use compression - thanks!